# libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line even after providing -lpthreads in cmake file

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, libwebsockets

I am trying to cross compile libwebsocket for arm-oe-linux-gnueabi but getting the error

```
/opt/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-generic/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.9.4/../../../../arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/lws-minimal-secure-streams-threads.dir/minimal-secure-streams-threads.c.obj: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_join@@GLIBC_2.4'
/opt/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-generic/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.9.4/../../../../arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: /opt/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-generic/bin/../arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [minimal-examples-lowlevel/secure-streams/minimal-secure-streams-threads/CMakeFiles/lws-minimal-secure-streams-threads.dir/build.make:100: bin/lws-minimal-secure-streams-threads] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5734: minimal-examples-lowlevel/secure-streams/minimal-secure-streams-threads/CMakeFiles/lws-minimal-secure-streams-threads.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:166: all] Error 2
```

The cmake file I am using is following

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CROSS_PATH /opt/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-generic/bin)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)


set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${CROSS_PATH}/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-g++")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${CROSS_PATH}/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc")

set(CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT "-lpthread")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread")
set(CMAKE_HAVE_THREADS_LIBRARY 1)
set(CMAKE_USE_WIN32_THREADS_INIT 0)
set(CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS_INIT 1)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lrt")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -lrt")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-error")
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${CROSS_PATH}")
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

cmake command issued is following

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../cross-compilation.cmake -DLWS_WITH_HTTP2=1 -DLWS_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/hasi/Desktop/compiled/include -DLWS_OPENSSL_LIBRARIES="/home/hasi/Desktop/compiled/lib/libssl.so;/home/hasi/Desktop/compiled/lib/libcrypto.so" -B .
```

how to fix this I am using ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS

Comment: Variable `CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT` and some other are set by [find_package(Threads)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindThreads.html) command. There is no sense to that them in the **toolchain**. What is your purpose by setting pthread-related variables in the toolchain file? If libwebsocket project uses `find_package(Threads)`, then this command should be able to correctly detect pthread support in gcc.

Comment: If you want to debug build errors, then you could run building with additional `VERBOSE=1` option and examine the command lines for presence/absence of pthread-related options. Useful information could also be extract from CMake output (when you run `cmake`): this output should contain lines about searching Threads.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I set pthread related variables because I got the same error before, so I thought setting up them will fix the issue. I added the `find_package(Threads REQUIRED)` and `project(libwebsockets C CXX)` to cmake file. Now I get `CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage`

Comment: Once again, it is NOT a purpose of a toolchain file to link with pthreads. Such linkage should be performed by the project itself (`CMakeLists.txt`). If the project uses `pthread_join` but doesn't call `find_package(Threads)`, then it is bug in the project, and it should be **fixed at the project scope**, not in the toolchain.